# Formulário Django

Tags: django

Bom dia Pessoal, estou fazendo um projeto django e já tenho um template que trabalhei em cima dele, estou querendo usar os formulários desse template para fazer suas operações com Django. O que consegui até o momento foi replicar os formulários como os formulários próprios do django, mas eu quero utilizar os formulários já existentes.
Meu código atualmente está assim:
HTML

```
<div class="modal-body">
                    <div class="form-group form-modal col-12">
                        <div class="row">
                            <label for="seguimento-cad" class="col-form-label col-3">Seguimento: </label>
                            <select class="form-control form-control-sm col-9" id="seguimento-cad" >
                                <option>Masculino</option>
                                <option>Feminino</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <label for="cidade-cad" class="col-form-label col-3">Cidade: </label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm col-9" id="cidade-cad" style="width: 320px">
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <label for="bairro-cad" class="col-form-label col-3">Bairro: </label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm col-9" id="bairro-cad" style="width: 320px">
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <label for="endereco-cad" class="col-form-label col-3">Endereço: </label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm col-9" id="endereco-cad" style="width: 320px">
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <label for="numero-cad" class="col-form-label col-3">Número: </label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm col-9" id="numero-cad" style="width: 320px">
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <label for="complemento-cad" class="col-form-label col-3">Complemento: </label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm col-9" id="complemento-cad" style="width: 320px">
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <label for="cep-cad" class="col-form-label col-3">Cep: </label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm col-9" id="cep-cad" style="width: 320px">
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <label for="telefone-cad" class="col-form-label col-3">Telefone: </label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm col-9" id="telefone-cad" style="width: 320px">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

forms.py

```
class empresa_cad(ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model = Empresa
    fields = ['nomeempresa', 'seguimentoempresa', 'cnpjempresa', 'seguimentoempresa', 'emailempresa',
              'senhaempresa', 'cepempresa', 'ufempresa', 'cidadeempresa', 'bairroempresa', 'logradouroempresa',
              'numeroenderecoempresa', 'complementoempresa']
```

View

```
def empresas(request):
empresas_list = Empresa.objects.all()
paginator = Paginator(empresas_list, 10)
page = request.GET.get('page')
empresas = paginator.get_page(page)

form_new = empresa_cad(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None)
if form_new.is_valid():
    form_new.save()

return render(request, 'core/empresas.html', {'empresas': empresas, 'form_empresa': form_new,
                                              'ultimo_id': ultimo_id)
```

Ao setar o {{ form_new }} dentro do formulário o cadastro funciona mas não sei como fazer com que os campos do django sejam utilizados pelo formulário existente.

Answer (score 0):

Para utilizar este form, você terá que utilizar os mesmos names e id's, para isto, você terá de setar os id's e names dos forms, você poderá fazer assim:

```
<div class="row">
    <label for="cidade-cad" class="col-form-label col-3">Cidade: </label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm col-9" name="{{ form.cidadeempresa.name }}" id="{{ form.cidadeempresa.auto_id }}" style="width: 320px">
</div>
<div class="row">
    <label for="bairro-cad" class="col-form-label col-3">Bairro: </label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm col-9" name="{{ form.bairroempresa.name }}" id="{{ form.bairroempresa.auto_id }}" style="width: 320px">
</div>
```

Note o "{{ form.cidadeempresa.auto_id }}" e {{ form.cidadeempresa.name }}, isto irá gerar os id's e names dos campos, que serão necessários para que você possa receber os valores via post.

Comment: Muito obrigado Victor, consegui aplicar no meu código :D

Comment: Fico feliz que pude ajudar ^^